# Kendo Range Slider Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

Despite contacting Telerik support directly I don't seem to be making any progress in solving my problem.

I am trying to filter my Kendo Grid within my MVC project using their range slider widget.  I am getting an error when I run my project which is:

[image: Error message from Firebug]

To me this says that the widget is perhaps being called before the Kendo.js and Jquery.js but it isn't.  The code in questions is in fact the last code before the closing < /body> tag.  I have doubled checked the requirements from Telerik and my javascript lirbaries are in the correct order.

Here is my source code for everything:

The Slider

```
@(Html.Kendo().RangeSlider()
    .Min(10)
    .Max(30)
    .Name("range_bhp")
)
```

The Grid (omitted for size)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.Models.tbl_my_requirements>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("Data_Read", "Grid").Data("getParameter"))
     )
)
```

The script

```
   function getParameter() {
            //debugger;
            return {

                range: $("#range_bhp").data("kendoRangeSlider").value()
            }
        }


        $(function () { //Ready
            $("#range_bhp").data("kendoRangeSlider").bind('change', function () {
                $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
            });
        });
```

Many thanks

Comment: Could you please provide page source (Ctrl + U) from browser?

Comment: I have solved the problem.  With these controls you need to place the slider widget BEFORE the Grid.  If I need to have them in a different order then I can use 1. .AutoBind(false) property 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-autoBind or Deferred() property
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/fundamentals#deferred-initialization

I've never come across this problem before but there is the answer :)